# Spring boot - best way to store images (SQL backend)

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, spring-boot

What is the best way to store images (taking into account space an time efficiency).

Let's say these images are used as profile pictures, so they would be fetched from the db frequently.

I have a few ideas in mind:

- Store images as Blob in the database OR
- Use filesystem in spring boot and store the images in a folder, then use/store string keys in the database to identify the images.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a really bad idea to store images in DB. you need to store only image links in DB (table with columns: user_id, profile_image_url), and image files should be stores in any distributed file system (like amazon S3)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! How about storing image files inside a folder in a remote server?

Comment: it depends on your app needs. if you want to play around, you could do that. but on production environment you might want to guarantee failover and it's better to store files inside distributed system.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server support blob storage inside the database, and also can integrate with Windows to store blobs in the file system (providing access both through TSQL and Windows APIs).

The features are called [Filestream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filestream-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) and [FileTables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filetables-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

The intent of these features is to provide the "best-of-both-worlds" for storing blob data.  SQL Server manages the consistency, availability and recoverability of all your application data, but large files are stored outside the database.

But the real point here is that since SQL Server supports storing blob data either inside the database files, or in the filesystem, Microsoft did a bunch of testing to help customers decide which was the better choice.

The testing resulted in a rule of thumb that under about 1MB in-database storage performs better than the file system, and above that the file system is better.  Basically external blobs have lower per GB cost and better streaming performance, but have higher per-file-access cost for opening, creating, deleting, etc.  And the breakeven point is around 1MB.

See eg this whitepaper on [Filestream Storage](http://download.microsoft.com/download/d/2/0/d20e1c5f-72ea-4505-9f26-fef9550efd44/filestreamstorage.docx)